# three js canvas texture transparency over an image texture

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh with texture made from canvas with transparent background. It looks fine when placed in front of objects with only .color set, but if the object has .map texture set (from either image or canvas), the transparency "goes through it", revealing plain .color of the object

Both front and back objects have phong material with .transparent = true,

and I use webgl renderer if it matters

Tell me please what am I dong wrong.

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted some code or even better a fiddle.